# Update table from column of a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables (just showing the parts that are relevant):

symbol:

```
symbol, exchange_id, sector, <several other columns>
abc,    1,           xyz
arc,    2,           dkg
```

sector:

```
symbol, sector
abc,    mno
```

The sector tables has all the correct sectors per symbol in it. I need to copy all the sectors from the sector table into the symbol table (overwriting any existing values) where the symbol in both tables match, but only where exchange_id=1

I have tried various options with no luck. I would have thought the following options would work but I get the error on both: table name 'symbol' specified more than once:

```
UPDATE symbol
SET symbol.sector = sector.sector
FROM symbol, sector
WHERE symbol.symbol = sector.symbol
AND symbol.exchange_id=1

UPDATE symbol
SET    symbol.sector = sector.sector
FROM   symbol
JOIN   sector ON symbol.symbol = sector.symbol
WHERE  symbol.exchange_id=1
```

I am using postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query this way:

```
UPDATE symbol s
SET    sector=t.sector
FROM   sector t
WHERE  s.symbol=t.symbol
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0ad7/1).

Comment: Excellent. I just had to add the condition for exchange_id=1. Then it worked. Thanks.